She (would)/(will) never leave me
This is a scene in a movie. A couple is talking about a man’s mother. His mother doesn’t like his girlfriend. He still loves his mother.

The girlfriend: You are a good son of your mother.
The man: Yes, I love her. She would never leave me.

I wonder that if I can use “will “ in this situation.
The man: “Sure, Yes, I love her. She “will” never leave me”
If it is ok to use “will “here, so what is the difference.

In practice both would and will mean the same thing here, but note that would is usually more idiomatic. Using will sounds a bit "dogmatic" (implying the speaker won't permit her to have even have the option of leaving). Using would simply implies no matter what future circumstances may arise, she will never leave.

This question is similar to: "Will never write" vs "Would never write" vs "Never write". If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

...but mothers do usually "leave" their sons! More accurately, sons usually leave their parents and the family home to live their own life (with or without a wife).

Take your pick of 'would vs will' questions on this site. Or just check a dictionary.

@FumbleFingers "leave" in this context is often meant as "abandon".

And for a husband or wife, "leave" typically means "divorce".

"leave" could mean "abandon" but it sounds a bit odd here. Although we don't know what the context is - it sounds something very dramatic, not just an everyday discussion.
